# Using PowerShell, how do I add multiple namespaces (one of which is the default namespace)?

Tags: powershell, namespaces

I have an XML document that contains two namespaces (the 'default' namespace and **xlink**):

- *xmlns="http://embassy/schemas/dudezilla/"*
- *xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"*

How do I specify "both" namespaces in my PowerShell code? PowerShell seems to want a prefix for the default namespace. How do I do this?

Right now I have the following code (not sure what to include for the default namespace):

```
    [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager] $nsmgr = $xml.NameTable;
    $nsmgr.AddNamespace('?','http://embassy/schemas/dudezilla/');
    [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager] $nsmgr = $xml.NameTable;
    $nsmgr.AddNamespace('xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');

    [System.Xml.XmlNodeList] $nodelist;
    [System.Xml.XmlElement] $root = $xml.DocumentElement;
    $nodelist = $root.SelectNodes("//image/@xlink:href", $nsmgr);

    Foreach ($xmlnode in $nodelist)
    {
        $xmlnode.Value;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 20):

PowerShell v2 makes this simpler:

```
$ns = @{
         dns="http://embassy/schemas/dudezilla/"
         xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       }

$xml | Select-Xml '//dns:image/@xlink:href' -Namespace $ns
```

If you want to do it the other way try:

```
$nsmgr = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager $xml.NameTable
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('dns','http://embassy/schemas/dudezilla/')
$nsmgr.AddNamespace('xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink')

$root = $xml.DocumentElement
$nodelist = $root.SelectNodes("//dns:image/@xlink:href", $nsmgr)

foreach ($xmlnode in $nodelist)
{
    $xmlnode.Value
}
```

Comment: In the first example above, I added the following to the last line get the value: `| foreach-object {
  $_.node.InnerXML
 }`

Comment: Can anybody explain why `$xml.NameTable` works even though there's no `NameTable` member on a `[System.Xml.XmlDocument]` object in PowerShell?

Comment: It helps for Powershell Error message "Select-Xml : Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function." with command `Select-Xml -Xpath '//test'`

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to use $null for the prefix of the default namespace ($null is equivalent to String.Empty in C#).

Working code:

```
    [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager] $nsmgr = $xml.NameTable;
    $nsmgr.AddNamespace($null,'http://embassy/schemas/dudezilla/');
    $nsmgr.AddNamespace('xlink','http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');

    [System.Xml.XmlNodeList] $nodelist;
    [System.Xml.XmlElement] $root = $xml.DocumentElement;
    $nodelist = $root.SelectNodes("//image/@xlink:href", $nsmgr);

    Foreach ($xmlnode in $nodelist)
    {
        $xmlnode.Value;
    }
```