# How do I remove the Private element (copy local) from csproj (xml) using Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell-2.0, csproj

I am trying to remove Project/ItemGroup/Reference/Private element from csproj xml.

```
    $csproj = [xml] ( Get-Content $fullProjectPath )

    $csproj.Project.ItemGroup | 
        ForEach-Object { $_.Reference } | 
        where { $_.Include -match "^(Some).+"} | 
        ForEach-Object { 
            if( $_.Private -ne $null ) { 
                $_.RemoveChild($_.SelectSingleNode("Private"))                                        
            } 
        }
```

I am getting an error $_.SelectSingleNode("Private"). Why it can find child node Private?

Comment: @Richard.  Exception calling "RemoveChild" with "1" argument(s): "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." 
i.e. $_.SelectSingleNode("Private") is returning a null object

Answer (score 2):

After providing the error information to @Richard question, I realized it must be something wrong with the XPath. What could be wrong in the simple XPath? I was trying to get the immediate child node. Then tried the classic debugging technique, write output to console, output the InnerXml of the parent node. In the output I noticed the xml output had namespace. So on further search on stackoverflow found out how to resolve xml namespace.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5277587/using-powershell-how-do-i-add-multiple-namespaces-one-of-which-is-the-default) for resolving namespace.  And the fixed script.

```
    $csproj = [xml] ( Get-Content $fullProjectPath )

    [System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager] $nsmgr = $xml.NameTable;
    $nsmgr.AddNamespace('msbuild','http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003');

    $csproj.Project.ItemGroup | 
        ForEach-Object { $_.Reference } | 
        where { $_.Include -match "^(Some).+"} |  
        ForEach-Object { 
            if( $_.Private -ne $null ) { 
                $_.RemoveChild($_.SelectSingleNode("msbuild:Private", $nsmgr)) 
            }
        }
```

Comment: +1 for working through this and discovering why stating the error rather than just "it doesn't work" is important, even before asking anyone else.

Comment: Thanks. I did try to debug before posting. But I guess its difficult to think straight towards the end of the day. And then following morning you find the answer easily.